# how to set tab distances in a textbox?

Tags: vba, tabs, textbox

I want other tab positions in a text box.

I have used

GetFocus

to get the handle of textbox (or window?),

and SendMessage and EM_SETTABSTOPS.

But I can't change the default TAB positions.

Comment: Is this for Access, Excel...?

Comment: Please show the complete code you have used in your trial. Also explain which line did not do what you expected when you single stepped it in the debugger

Comment: Are you referring to a Tab index? Is your text box situated on a Form?

Comment: it is in word.

every line completes without error.

the textbox is in a page of a multipage in a userform.
but i have tested it in a userform without multipage.